Same code produces differing results page to page
Here is my MWE
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\NewDocumentCommand{\redRule}{}{%
    {\color{red}\hrule}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\exy}{ m m m}{%
    ``#1''&\textbf{#2}&#3\\
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Sec}{ m O{2.5em}}{%
    \pagebreak
    \vspace{-5em}
    \begin{centering}
        \section{\kern -11pt \xdash[#2]#1.}
    \end{centering}
    \vspace{1em}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xdash}{O{3em}}{%
    \rule[0.4ex]{#1}{0.55pt}%
}
\newcolumntype{C}{w{c}{117.45999pt}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{117.45999pt}}

\sectionfont{\normalsize}
\def\thesection{\Roman{section}.}
\EveryShipout{%
    \redRule
    \begin{tabular}{ C C C }
        \emph{English.}&\emph{Gaelic.}&\emph{Orthoepy.}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{1em}
}

\begin{document}
    {\Large\textbf{Title Page as Filler…}}
    \Sec{Adjectives}
    \begin{longtable}{ L | L | L }
        \exy{cold, hot}{fuar, teth}{f\={u}ur tjà}
        \exy{large}{mòr}{mòr}
    \end{longtable}
    \Sec{More Stuff}
    \begin{longtable}{ L | L | L }
        \exy{cold, hot}{fuar, teth}{f\={u}ur tjà}
        \exy{large}{mòr}{mòr}
    \end{longtable}
    \Sec{Yet More Stuff}
    \begin{longtable}{ L | L | L }
        \exy{cold, hot}{fuar, teth}{f\={u}ur tjà}
        \exy{large}{mòr}{mòr}
    \end{longtable}
    \Sec{Yet More Stuff Again}
    \begin{longtable}{ L | L | L }
        \exy{cold, hot}{fuar, teth}{f\={u}ur tjà}
        \exy{large}{mòr}{mòr}
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}

I would like the distance from the first line of the table to the header and from that to the page number to be fixed. That was my intent with the code. Yet, it seems to be different for each page. I have no idea why and would like to know. Even better would be instruction on fixing whatever is wrong. I'm trying to duplicate text from the turn of the last century and have the need for more control over the result.

Please make your MWE compilable.

@Zarko It compiles OK for me with LuaTeX. Do you get an error?

Yes, wrong placement of &. Also C and L are not defined, etc. I try to test with LuaLaTeX

@Zarko They are defined. Right after \xdash is defined. And I don't get an error for the &s. Maybe something went wrong with the copy-paste?

Sorry, now i find this definition, but error persist.  Sorry, temporary i haven't spare time, I will be back around noon.

@cfr, similar, but showing difference page to page? BTW, what did you do to fix the boxes?

@cfr, that is exactly what I'm looking for!

@cfr, Of course, but that is an artifact of the problem if you are talking about the vertical overlap. The idea was that I could modify the v-macros in \Sec to find a good placement. There are two cases: pages with a section header and pages without. If the relationship between the first line of the table the column header and the page number is fixed, it should be possible to tweak the macros for a good looking arrangement.

The hook you're adding material to at shipout shouldn't be used to add anything to the vertical list (ltshipout-doc). It isn't, in fact, getting added to the currently shipping out page, but to the next one. This will pretty much inevitably screw things up in unexpected ways (page 3 -\EveryShipout is using shipout/before).
This is why you don't get the material showing on the first page, even though it is supposed to be added to all pages. (I realise you may not want it added to the first page, but that's what adding it to the hook is attempting to do.)
You're also failing to end the first paragraph i.e. the 'title' appropriately. This is why the title is centred, even though you did nothing obvious to centre it. It is centred because \Sec creates a centred paragraph. In fact, there is no centering environment. There is center and \centering. You're effectively using \centering for the paragraph, which includes the 'title'. This also results in a paragraph which uses different font sizes, which may not be helping.
Note that you are also making \parskip add glue in standard cases. Moreover, longtable itself uses skips (which include glue) at the beginning and end of the environment.
There is actually no purpose to using longtable here as you are starting a new one on every page.
The overfull horizontal boxes are not helping and, if consistency (or just decent output) is your goal, you should eliminate them.
\newlength\ltlength
\AddToHook {begindocument/end}
{% load the calc package or use \dimexpr
  \setlength\ltlength{(\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth)/3}%
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{\ltlength}}%
}

Finally, note that there is no point in setting dimensions to things like 14.49999pt or whatever. TeX calculations are only approximate. When fancyhdr gives you that as a minimum dimension, use 14.5pt or 15pt. The 14.4999pt is likely the effect of storing 14.5pt anyway and then retrieving the value to report on the terminal/in the log.
Beyond saying 'don't use shipout/before', however, it is hard to know what to positively recommend because it isn't clear what your real purpose is. (Why use longtable if you start a new one each page? Is it really a table? Or would a different technique be better? Should some of the repeated material be in your page header rather than the page itself? It's difficult to make sense of what motivates your markup ....)
If you really want to add material at shipout, use shipout/background or shipout/foreground and add the material, which gets wrapped in a picture environment. Otherwise, consider using marks or repeated longtable headings or ....
To get a sense of what's going on, I added this code from ltpara-doc to the preamble:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% ltpara-doc.pdf 
\newcounter{paracnt}% sequence counter
\newcounter{paralevel}% level counter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_para_seq
\cs_new:Npn \ParaPush
{
  \seq_gpush:No \g_para_seq {\the\value{paracnt}}
}
\cs_new:Npn \ParaPop {\seq_gpop:NNF \g_para_seq \paracntvalue \ERROR }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{para/begin}{%
  \stepcounter{paracnt}\stepcounter{paralevel}%
  \ParaPush
  \typeout{PARA: \arabic{paracnt}-\roman{paralevel} start
    (\@currenvir\space env.\on@line)}%
  \llap{\color{red}\tiny\arabic{paracnt}\}%
  }%
}
\AddToHook{para/end}{%
  \ParaPop
  \typeout{PARA: \paracntvalue-\roman{paralevel} end \space\space
    (\@currenvir\space env.\on@line)}%
  \rlap{\color{red}\tiny\ \paracntvalue}%
  \addtocounter{paralevel}{-1}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

This shows the start and end of each paragraph and their ordering. In particular, it shows that the material allegedly added at shipout is processed prior to every other paragraph on the page. Reading ltshipout-doc explains why this is the case.
I also used
\AddToHook{shipout/before}{% DO NOT USE
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter
  \redRule
  \showthe\parskip
  \showthe\c@page
  \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{ X X X }
    \emph{English.}&\emph{Gaelic.}&\emph{Orthoepy.}\\
  \end{tabularx}
  \vspace{1em}
}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\parindent=0pt

but this will not compile in most editors. Either compile at the command line or change \show to \typeout.
So this is not a solution-type answer. It is more of a here's-some-of-what's-happening with some pointers to things-you-shouldn't-do and possible things-you-might-do-instead. Which of those things you want to do, I'm not sure, but hopefully you will know.
[By the way, which Gaelic?]

An very instructive answer. Note I think \dimexpr is missing in \setlength\ltlength.

@pascal974 Thanks! Actually, I think I loaded calc, in which case you don't need it, but then forgot when I excerpted the code.

Scottish Gaelic (I'm tempted to say "Of Course!", but I won't.)

To answer some of your questions, the tables in the mwe are short to keep the text to a minimum. However, they span more than one page in the actual text —hence the need for the header at ship out. The occasional item that is problematic is the section title. Another point is that I want the pseudo-header below the section title. It must maintain a constant relationship with the table. The good news for me is that it is all tables, all the way down!

BTW, much of your code is currently beyond me as my LaTeX3-fu is quite young (infant-stage.)

@hsmyers It's not mine. As I said in my answer, I just copy-pasted that bit from ltpara-doc. Even the comments are copied.

If you want a header on each page for a longtable, why aren't you using a header? You really don't want to add it at ship out. Even if you put it in an appropriate shipout hook (background or foreground), it won't work properly as a header. One of the reasons to use longtable is because it offers e.g. \endhead, \endfirsthead and so on. That's how you should handle the headers for multi-page tables. Then there's no problem maintaining a relationship with the table because they are part of it. Or are you saying you want section headings in the middle of such a table?

And, yes. Sorry about the Gaelic question. I'm afraid I don't know enough to distinguish them. And it isn't like Breton, where I could maybe guess - at least if I could figure out the pronunciation. Interesting that mòr means large.

I admit to not looking at the details of longtable! I will shortly, thanks.

beag pronounced like big means small, just to keep you on your feet!

@hsmyers In Welsh, the word for 'she' is pronounced like the English 'he'.

Yeah, languages are like that.
